# Security & Privacy/Accessibility not updating permissions

Tags: applescript

I've got a bit of applescript that I wrote that presses a couple window buttons on screen for me.  On use, I get a pop-up saying I need to grant permissions in 'Security & Privacy -> Accessibility'.  The checkbox to enable permissions does not work; it's not greyed out, it just doesn't take.
[image: bundle added, but no apparent effect when clicking checkbox]

My understanding is that the TCC.db is the underlying implementation of the Accessibility permissions.  This is what the 'access' table looks like immediately after I attempt to launch the app:
`$ sudo sqlite3 "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db" 'select * from access'
kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.company.applet|0|0|1||`

Here's what the table looks like after I try to click the checkbox to enable permissions:
`$ sudo sqlite3 "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db" 'select * from access'
kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.company.applet|0|0|1||
kTCCServiceAccessibility|/Users/luser/Applications/applet.app|1|1|1||`

From this, my theory is that the accessibility permission mechanism is seeing the app as two different names -- com.company.applet vs install path.  But I don't know enough about macOS to proceed with troubleshooting.  Can anyone help me understand what's going on?  Does anyone have ideas on how to get this working?

Thanks!

Additional details:

My build process is to feed my applescript into osacompile, which generates the ~/Applications/applet.app bundle.  I then manually add CFBundleIdentifier with `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :CFBundleIdentifier string "com.company.applet"' ~/Applications/applet.app/Contents/Info.plist`.  If I leave out the plist CFBundleIdentifier update, the application still fails the accessibility check.

I can build the bundle in Script Editor and everything works.  However, this is not a desirable long-term solution; as I want to keep everything in version control.  The generated artifacts from Script Editor are binary, and thus unsuitable for git.

Finally, it looks like in previous versions of macOS, I could have modified TCC.db directly, but now all my writes fail -- elsewhere, I've seen this attributed to SIP.  I don't want to disable SIP.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This is a well written question and deserves and up vote before I ask some questions, +1. Does it make and difference if you use `defaults` to write the `CFBundleIdentifier`? Also, just as a test, if after creating the app the way you prefer, if you just open it in Script Editor, hit Compile and then Save, and close it before adding it to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility, does it then allow it to be checked without issue?

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Using Defaults does not make a difference; the permissions are not enabled.

Compiling&saving with Script Editor also offers no magic fix.  Intriguingly, the application stops appearing at all in the TCC.db database after this.

I should also note that `defaults read` fails to find the application by domain (i.e. com.company.applet)

-- and wow, comments are limited; thus the many edits.